# close pop-up with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im having a little trouble with a simple chrome extension that close a specific pop-up by its link.

When the pop-up window is popping up the main page is getting disable, and as soon as the pop-up is close, the page is enable again.

The problem I'm struggling with is that when I run my extension, the pop-up is more like being removed instead of being closed. so the pop-up window is disappearing, but the main page keeps on being disable.

BUT, if I run the javascript in the chrome dev-console the pop-up is closing correctly and the main page gets enable right away.

is this a bug? or are they other ways to close a window instead of `window.close()`

this is the simple javascript I'm using

```
(function(){
        var x = document.URL;

        var url = "www.xxxx.com/customurl";

            if(x==url){
                    window.close();
            }

    })();
```

Manifest

```
{
    "name": "ReportCloser",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
            ],
        "run_at": "document_end" ,
        "js": ["script.js"]     
        }
    ], 
    "manifest_version":2
}
```

Comment: If you aren't using it on a function prompted with a click, window.close doesn't work.

Comment: Well since I want it to run without user interference, I have put the script in a self invoking function. Will update my question.

Comment: You can do it if the parent is doing that

Comment: Where is that code in your extension?

Comment: hi @Xan:)
Its in my script.js file.

Comment: Which is.. what? Your manifest would help.

Comment: @Xan Sorry, missed to save the update. now its there

Answer (score 1):

So this was my problem.

The pop-up window got closed to fast, before the content was loaded.
fixed that problem with an timeout.

```
setTimeout("window.close()",500);
```

Works like a charm now :)